# can't get response headers in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my controller, I have the following before_action...

```
def cors_set_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
end
```

I'm trying write a test to make sure that these headers are set with the following code...

```
describe 'cors headers action ' do
  it 'sets the proper headers' do
    get :jobs, format: :json
    p response.headers
    expect(response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin']).to eq('*')
    expect(response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods']).to eq('POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS')
    expect(response.headers['Access-Control-Request-Method']).to eq('*')
    expect(response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers']).to eq('Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization')
  end
end
```

The only headers coming back when I do p response.headers are - {"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Content-Type"=>"text/html; charset=utf-8"}

This works in my app just fine, but not the test.  So, any idea what the issue might be?  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it gets rewritten somehow before it’s sent to client? Isn’t after_action more appropriate to set response headers?

Comment: Thanks for the idea but if that were the case, then I wouldn't expect to see those headers in the browser when I run the app... yet I do.  As for after_action vs. before_action, I'm not quite sure, but I tried that and the test still fails with the same results.

Comment: Checked on rails 4.2 with rspec 3.2. It works fine. Shouldn't you use :index instead of :jobs here: 'get :jobs, format: :json' ?

Comment: Got it figured out and it was a stupid mistake on my part.  I have validation that fires before certain methods and due to this validation it was bypassing the cors method.  All fixed up now.  Thanks.

Comment: @geoffswartz Can you close this question then?